# Database reports different character lengths for the same word

Tags: mysql

I have a table in which I added english dictionary words. Now I have some records that seem to be duplicates but the length of the string differs.

for example 'aaron' is repeated twice in my table, but when I use this query:

```
select id, word, char_length(word) from my_table;
```

I get the following back:

```
id | word  | char_length
 7 | aaron |  5
12 | aaron |  6
```

How can the `char_length` change for the same word? What can I do to remove one word which exceeds length by 1?

Comment: The extra characters are probably some whitespace. Try `TRIM`-ing it.

Answer (score 0):

It's likely @Vatev is on the right track with his comment.

Try these two queries:

```
1. SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE word = 'aaron';
2. SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE word like '%aaron%';
```

The first will only match rows where word is exactly `aaron` while the second will match rows which contain aaron anywhere.  If there are rows with extra content, like whitespace, they would show up in the second, but not the first.

One possible way to clean up these duplicates would be to run the following:

```
DELETE FROM my_table WHERE TRIM(word) != word;
```

But don't run that blindly - it will delete *all* rows with extra whitespace, even if there isn't a matching "correct" entry.